# Cut String in a text file using windows batching

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've a log file contains lines like this

> 00:02:38
>   03/24/2015    disabled    concurrent  Depo_work_Shift_Manager disabled by
>   schedule  13:110590   200 31  n/a n/a n/a

I would like to loop over file and cut only "concurrent Depo_work_Shift_Manager" to put them in another file using windows batching script.

I tried the following

> for /F "tokens=4,5" %A in (file.txt) do echo %A > Group.txt

but it's only getting "concurrent" part, would you please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... "tokens=4,5" %A ...
```

Two tokens, first is `%A` and second `%B`, so

```
.... echo %A %B ....
```